# Optimising Angular Js e-commerce project

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm working on a AngularJs project whose loading time is too high >15sec. It has got too many Js and Css files how to optimise? As the page loads everything at once of 1st time loading. I want to make the Js and Css loading on demand.

From where to start so that I can optimise? please suggest some good guidelines and workflows.

Comment: example of article. http://blog.jhades.org/what-every-angular-project-likely-needs-and-a-gulp-build-to-provide-it/  . You need js and css minification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some points to consider:

1. Make sure your CSS, JavaScript and HTML files are being served with gzip encoding. This will dramatically reduce the amount of data which needs to be transferred on pageload.
2. Ensure your JS and CSS is minified, which eliminates whitespace and reduces the size of the files.
3. Try to remove dependencies on large, bulky libraries. JQuery is huge, and often more lightweight libraries can be used instead.
4. Take a look at Google's PageSpeed module for Apache and NGINX. This can perform several magic tasks such as compiling your javascript and css into single files. https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/
5. If you use a compatible webserver, consider enabling HTTP2 (or SPDY on older servers).

**Content Delivery Networks**

Some people promote the use of public Content Delivery Networks (CDNs, such as [maxcdn](https://www.maxcdn.com)) to serve your JavaScript files. This has several potential advantages:

- With popular libraries, it's likely the files will already be cached in the browsers of people who are visiting your site.
- CDNs are generally globally distributed, which should make them fast and responsive worldwide.

However, I personally disagree, and I make sure that all my 3rd party JavaScript libraries are served locally. Here's why:

- If a CDN is offline or having issues, your site will be broken (though this can be patched somewhat with [fallback loading](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx))
- If a CDN is overloaded or saturated, your site will also be slow
- It adds at least one additional DNS lookup on page load, which is another point of failure
- If the CDN gets compromised, someone could place some malicious javascript on your site (this can be avoided by using the ["integrity" checksum](https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/bootstrapcdn-subresource-integrity/))
- CDN served files cannot be inlined, combined and optimised by Google Pagespeed
- CDN served files cannot be pipelined with the rest of your site

Comment: thanks a lot.  Your points are working and even giving results. Actually my project has some other problems as well like Js dependency. So until a Js get downloaded others are waiting to start their task.

Comment: I've added some more info about CDNs :)

Comment: Thanks Tom due to your suggestions my PageSpeed score has increased from 32 to 73 as well as I've enabled GZip also :)

Comment: can you suggest any way so that I can compress images that are coming from 3rd party websites ??